# Cyclic csv-Import to SQL file by file

Tags: sql, powershell, loops, csv

I try to write a short script that cyclic imports csv-files to a SQL data table that are being dropped in an import folder ($sourceSQL). Each csv-file consists of one line of information (here three columns). To make sure that the file was successfully written to the data table, I check if the unique Id can be found in the table. 
So far it works with the first file. However, the second file gets only moved to the destination folder without being written to the data table. I can't find the problem. Is it because of the $data variable?

```
$StartButton.Add_Click({
$script:ActiveLoop   = $true

while ($script:ActiveLoop){

   If (Test-Path $sourceSQL){ 
     $data = $null
     Do{
       $data = import-csv $impcsv -Header A,B,C
       foreach($i in $data)
       { 
       $Id = $i.A
       $State = $i.B 
       $Sequence = $i.C

       $query = INSERT INTO $SQLTable (Id, State, Sequence)
       VALUES ('$Id','$State','$Sequence')"
       $impcsv = invoke-sqlcmd -Database $SQLDatabase -Query $query  -serverinstance $SQLInstance -Username $SQLUsername -Password $SQLPassword}

      $SqlQueryId = "SELECT TOP 1 Id from $SQLTable ORDER BY Id DESC"
      $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
      $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLInstance; Database = $SQLDatabase; User ID = $SQLUsername; Password = $SQLPassword"
      $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
      $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQueryId 
      $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
      $SqlConnection.Open() 
      $IdCheck= [string]$SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
      $SqlConnection.Close()
     } Until ($Id -eq $IdCheck)

   Move-Item $sourceSQL -Destination $destinationSQL

   }   
   [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
 }
 })
 $objForm.Controls.Add($StartButton)
```

Comment: You only import one CSV file `$data = import-csv $impcsv -Header A,B,C`. If there are more, you need to surround that whole block of code inside the `Do {...}` loop with a `Get-ChildItem -Path <PATH TO THE CSV FILES> -Filter '*.csv'` construct. Mistakes I can see: (1) your `foreach($i in $data){` does not have a closing curly bracket and (2) `$query = ` lacks an opening double-quote character.

Comment: Mistake (1) and (2) happened during editing the code in here. Sorry! $impcsv is defined as $impcsv = "C:\desktop\sourceSQL\\*.csv". My first attempt was, to avoid that there are two files to import at the same time. However it might be a lot easier for me, if there could be mutliple files in the folder and the script imports (and moves) them one by one. However I'm totally unexperienced how to deal with this. Could you please give me one more hint?

Comment: Trying to use Get-ChildItem -Path $impcsv -Filter '*.csv', I realize that -Header A,B,C won't work. Why is my While-Loop not cyclic importing a new CSV file?